# Run command pipes with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, command, pipe

How can I run the following command using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)?

```
mysqldump database_name table_name | bzip2 > filename
```

I know [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) can do the job but I dont want to wait for the dump to finish in main program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `shell=True` option to make it execute shell commands:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("sleep 4s && echo right thar, right thar",shell=True);
print 'i like it when you put it'
```

which yields:

```
 I like it when you put it
 [4 seconds later]
 right thar, right thar
```